# Iterating through start, finish and class values in Python

Tags: python, loops, datetime, dataframe, range

I have a little script that creates a new column in my pandas dataset called class, and assigns class values for a given time range. It works well, but suddenly I have thousands of time ranges to input, and wondered if it might possible to write some kind of loop which gets the three columns (start, finish, and class) from a pandas dataframe.

[image: dataset1]
[image: dataset2]

To complicate things, the time ranges are of irregular interval in dataframe 1 (e.g. a nanosecond, 30 seconds, 4 minutes) and in dataframe 2, (which contains accelerometer data) the time series data increases in increments of 0.010 seconds.  Any help appreciated as I'm new to Python.

```
conditions = [(X['DATETIME'] < '2017-11-17 07:31:07') & (X['DATETIME']>= '2017-11-17 00:00:00'),(X['DATETIME'] < '2017-11-17 07:32:35') & (X['DATETIME']>= '2017-11-17 07:31:07'),(X['DATETIME'] < '2017-11-17 09:01:05') & (X['DATETIME']>= '2017-11-17 08:58:39')]
classes = ['0','1','2']
X['CLASS'] = np.select(conditions, classes, default='5')
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit on what exactly the task would be, maybe show an example of the transformation that you would like to see implemented, etc.

Comment: Yes, sure. So the completed product would be five columns:
Datetime - X - Y - Z - CLASS
So for instance, 2017-11-26 02:00:00:330, 0.1444, 0.0571, -0.9778, 0
Where zero indicates sedentary behaviour.

Comment: I'm sure it could be automated, I just still do not really understand the way you would like to get the Class column. I think that it should be something like take the states from the table and based on those assign values to the class column. Is your second table also available as a dataframe, have you transformed the time data to datetime format?

Comment: Yes to both questions. I think so too, it feels just beyond my reach. Was thinking some kind of syntax for substituting date range with Start and Finish parameters with  "for value in Start.." loop until end of values...

Comment: Okay, I get it now, I'll try to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible solutions to this, you could use for loops as you said, etc. But if you are new to Python, I think this answer would show you more about the power of python and its great packages. I will use the `numpy` package here. And I suppose that your first table is in a pandas data frame named `X` while the second in one named `condidtions`.

```
import numpy as np
X['CLASS'] = conditions['CLASS'].iloc[np.digitize(X['Datetime'].view('i8'),
                                                  conditions['Start'].view('i8')) - 1]
```

Don't worry, I won't let you there. So `np.digitize` takes it's first list and bins it based on the bin borders defined by the second argument. So here you will get the index of the `condition` corresponding to the time in the given row.

There are a couple of details to be noted:

- `.view('i8')` provides a view of the `datetime` object which can be easily used by the `numpy` package (if you are interested, you can read more about the details)
- `-1` is needed to realign the results (the value after the start of the first condition will get a value of `1`, but we want it to start from `0`.
- in the end we use the `iloc` function of the `conditions['CLASS']` series to map these indices to the class values.

Comment: Thank you zsomko. I'm not sure yet how this will be able to loop through my start, finish and class fields for each time range, so I may have to continue this conversation off-forum, but I'm grateful for the effort as it seems it will bring me closer anyway.

Comment: It's using dataframe functionality -> operations are usually done row by row, some kind of inherent loop for the dataframe. The digitize operation will do the search in fact based on the two series passed, and then based on the search you just assign the values. Have you tried it? Does it do what you expect?